# Ctrl-b does not work

Tags: windows-10, tmux

With Bash now being available on Windows I tried using tmux, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> + [other key]` does not work for me or [any of the other key combinations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/06/08/tmux-support-arrives-for-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/).

As far as I can tell Windows is not overriding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> key combo. I have tried creating a `tmux.conf` file and hard setting the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> setting, but it doesn’t seem to have any effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is control B meant to do?